# How to find duplicate rows in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to find duplicate entries in a data set using JPA?

```
| id | text |
-------------
| 1  | foo  |
| 2  | bar  |
| 3  | foo  |
```

I want to have only entries 1 & 3 in my set.
I can't make it unique on this field.

—

DISTINCT would give me rows 1 & 2.

If it’s a query, a join with the same table? I’m not sure how that would work. I couldn’t get group by to function.

Comment: I'd settle for a count and change my UI design, but I can't figure that out either :-/

Comment: why not do a query? and set the where clause so that you compare the candidate with a subquery of the same entity type, and set a condition of text being the same but id being different (between candidate and subquery)

Comment: You want to find the entries with `text = foo`?

Comment: Yes, that's the duplicate. I want to exclude rows which are not duplicated.

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks, this is a helpful comment. Sadly my SQL is more rusty than I thought... I think this is the answer Cascader has given

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya in a sense yes, but only because they are duplicate. I won't know that `text=foo` in advance. Also there might be three or more matches, and there will be other duplicates too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply common practice from SQL to JPQL with the following query:

`SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.text IN (SELECT text FROM Entity d GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1`.

A sub-query is required so you'd need an index on `text` column for it to be efficient.

Comment: The 'IN' clause! Thank you I will try this and report back on progress. Good tip about indices too - that'll become important as this will be dealing with a lot of data.

Comment: Super close! `SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.text IN (SELECT text FROM Entity d GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )` - the entities in the Select must be in the Group By list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**
I believe you can use the following syntax without inner query:

```
SELECT id, text, COUNT(*) FROM entity GROUP BY text HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Good suggestion but this would give me 'foo' and 'bar, and not just 'foo'

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question at first. I've just edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it maybe wasn't completely clear (and I can't add comments via the mobile site for some reason). Thanks, this also looks viable; I like very much that it's a single query. I'll try this and feedback

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work, JPA wanted me to have id in the GROUP BY clause, which wuold have messed up the grouping as the IDs are unique.